# How do I work with SASS' new module system when it comes to variables?

Tags: sass

I am working on a project that consists of multiple web portals based on a different target audience. The portals share the same HTML "components" and differ mostly in color, but additional style difference may exist.

Until now, I've used the following folder structure:

```
sass
├── default
│   ├── components
│   │   └── component-1.scss
│   └───_variables.scss
├── portal-a
│   ├── components
│   │   └── component-1.scss (portal-a specific code)
│   ├── _variables.scss
│   └── app.scss
└── portal-b
    ├── _variables.scss
    └── app.scss
```

`default` contains the default styles for all components as well as global variables.

`portal-*` contains additional portal-specific styling for a component (if any) as well as portal-specific variables like colors, fonts, spacing, etc.

Each `portal-*` also contains an `app.scss` that serves as entry point and it's what the final CSS is built from. It contains the following:

```
@import "../default/_variables";
@import "./_variables";
@import "../default/components/**/*.scss";
@import "./components/**/*.scss";
```

So basically it includes the default variables first, then the portal-specific variables overwriting the default values, then all `scss` files from `default` and finally the portal-specific component stylesheets.

This whole setup works, but I would like to switch to SASS' new component model with `@use` and `@forward`, but I am totally lost.

---

So let's say I have my `sass/default/_variables.scss`:

```
$font-size: 16px !default;
$text-color: #000000 !default;
$padding-base: 25px !default;
```

Then I have `sass/portal-a/_variables.scss` where I only want to redefine the text color:

```
$text-color: #ff0000;
```

I assume I also have to forward the default variables, so `sass/portal-a/_variables.scss` should eventually contain:

```
@forward "../default/_variables";

$text-color: #ff0000;
```

Right? (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Same deal for `portal-b`, but with a different value, `sass/portal-b/_variables.scss`:

```
@forward "../default/_variables";

$text-color: #0000ff;
```

So now that I have variables set-up, I want to write the default stylesheet of a component. I create a file `sass/default/components/component-1.scss`.

```
[data-component="component-1"] {
  font-size: how do I access the font-size variable?;
  color: how do I access the text-color variable?;
  padding: 2 * how do I access the padding-base variable?;
}
```

Then I create my entry points from which the final CSS files are going to be built.

`sass/portal-a/app.scss` and `sass/portal-b/app.scss`:

```
@use "_variables"

@use "../default/components/component-1";
```

That first `@use "_variables"` should theoretically load the default variables, overwrite the default value for the text color, but then how do I pass everything so `component-1.scss` can access it?